# usages of obstacle, interrupt, and obstacle

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

**Obstacles** such as the tress avoided us to see the sea.

The trees were **obstruct** our view of the sea.

The trees **interrupted** our view of the sea.

I am wondering whether the bold parts could mean the same thing.

Other than that, would you correct the first sentence in a way that it could mean the similar meaning like the two other sentences.

In addition, would you please learn me other synonym for the following?

our view of

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *Obstacles* is fine in your first example, but you cannot use *avoid* in this context. *Avoid* designates an action which the subject does **not** take:

  > Kris ***avoided*** looking at the sea, because it made him nauseous.

  To express an action which keeps someone else from doing something you may use *prevent*:

  > Obstacles such as the trees ***prevented*** us from seeing the sea.
- *Were obstruct* is not grammatical English; the progressive construction requires the present participle:

  > The trees ***were obstructing*** our view of the sea.
- Your third example is fine. The only alternatives to *view (of)* I can think of which will work with *interrupt* are *line of sight (to)* and *sightline (to)*; but these are  rather technical and would not ordinarily be used in casual contexts:

  > Sightlines in older theatres were often interrupted by columns or restricted by inadequate rakes.
  >
  > At this point trees interrupted our line of sight to the tank formation, and we were unable to bring our artillery to bear until we posted a spotter 200 yards to the west.